# Product with Invertible Matrices Question

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

If $A$ is an $n \times k$ matrix and $B$ is a $k \times l$ matrix (for some finite positive integers), and if $B^TB$ is invertible, and if $B^TA^TAB$ is invertible, does this imply $A^TA$ is also invertible?

Edit: What if we assume $A$ is square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not true. try the following matrices

$\begin{array}{l}
B = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
2&1\\
3&4\\
4&2
\end{array}} \right]\\
A = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&2&3\\
1&2&4
\end{array}} \right]
\end{array}$

Comment: $B^TB$ is invertible means $rank(B)=l$. 
$B^TA^TAB$ is invertible means $rank(AB)=l$.
So if you choose $l>k$ and matrix $rank(A)=n$ where $n=l<k$ leads to singular $A^TA$.

Comment: So what happens if I assume $A$ is square? Would it hold then?

Comment: Try $A = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&2&3\\
1&2&4\\
1&2&5
\end{array}} \right]$

Answer (score 0):

In general this is not true; for instance if $B$ is a vector row of size $1\times n$; then $B^TB$ has rank equal to $1$ and so this not invertible unless $n=1$ and $B$ is the non-zero element.